# how to apply a multiplier on a dataframe based on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this first dataframe `df_1`:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,1,3,1],
                     'symbol':['A','B','C','A','A'],
                     'date':['2021-02-12','2021-02-09','2021-02-14','2021-02-02','2021-02-05'],
                     'value':[1,1,1,1,1]})
```

```
   id symbol        date  value
0   1      A  2021-02-12      1
1   2      B  2021-02-09      1
2   1      C  2021-02-14      1
3   3      A  2021-02-02      1
4   1      A  2021-02-05      1
```

And given this second `df_2`:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_symbol':['1_A', '1_A'],
                     'init_date':['2021-02-01','2021-02-01'],
                     'end_date':['2021-02-05', '2021-02-12'],
                     'multiplier':[5,2]})
```

I need to apply this `df_2.multiplier` on `df_1` for rows on `df_1.value` where the concat of `id` and  `_` and `symbol` is equals the `df_2.id_symbol`, and if the `df_1.date` is within the `df_2.init_date` and `df_2.end_date`.

My result should be like this, after the code:

```
   id symbol        date   value
0   1      A  2021-02-12       2
1   2      B  2021-02-09       1
2   1      C  2021-02-14       1
3   3      A  2021-02-02       1
4   1      A  2021-02-05      10
```

5 = 1 * 5 // 10 = 1 * 5 * 2

My both dataframes are quite bigger than this.

Comment: I have many dates intervals in df_2. so I can multiply the value in df_1 more than once

Comment: @DanielArges Is your dataframe `df_2` always contains unique values in the column `id_symbol`?

Comment: unique, only one, although it varies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's the possibility of multiplying the value more than once we will do a merge, find all possible matches and sum the multipliers to figure out how much we need to multiply the original row by.

First split the 'id_symbol' column and use `datetime64` dtypes so we can do merges and comparisons:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['date'])
df_2['init_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['init_date'])
df_2['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['end_date'])

df_2[['id', 'symbol']] = df_2['id_symbol'].str.split('_', expand=True)
df_2['id'] = df_2['id'].astype('int64')
```

Now merge on all possible multipliers, but set it to 1 if it's outside of the date range. Determine the total multiplier for that row (i.e. product of all multipliers that satisfy the date condition) and use that to multiply the with the original DataFrame (aligns on df_1's Index).

```
mult = df_1.reset_index().merge(df_2, on=['id', 'symbol'], how='left')
mult['multiplier'] = np.where(mult.date.between(mult.init_date, mult.end_date), 
                              mult.multiplier, 1)
mult = mult.groupby('index')['multiplier'].prod()
#index
#0     2.0
#1     1.0
#2     1.0
#3     1.0
#4    10.0
#Name: multiplier, dtype: float64

df_1['value'] = df_1['value']*mult
```

---

```
print(df1)
   id symbol       date  value
0   1      A 2021-02-12    2.0
1   2      B 2021-02-09    1.0
2   1      C 2021-02-14    1.0
3   3      A 2021-02-02    1.0
4   1      A 2021-02-05   10.0
```

Comment: It worked, even with the edited question. great. If I want to use `mult.groupby()`, where do I need to substitute?

Comment: @DanielArges I'm not sure I understand what you'd want to do with that. `mult` up to that point is a DataFrame and then I group over the original DataFrame index to figure out the total multiplicative factor for each row based on all of the possible rows it could have merged with (so it becomes a simple Series I added and commented out)

Comment: Never mind. your solution works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get to your desired outcome with the following process. I will comment on the code to explain each step, but it is fairly simple:

```
# Our imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the id_symbol column in df_1 and perform a left merge
df_1['id_symbol']=df_1['id'].astype(str)+"_"+df_1['symbol'].astype(str)
df_1 = pd.merge(df_1,df_2,how='left',on='id_symbol')

# Make sure you convert to datetime, and handle the NaT succesfully
for i in ['init_date','end_date']:
    df_1[i] = pd.to_datetime(df_1[i],errors='coerce')

# Use np.where to check whether the conditions you want are satisfied
df_1['value'] = np.where((df_1['init_date'] <= df_1['date']) & (df_1['date']  <= df_1['end_date']),
                         df_1['value']*df_1['multiplier'],1) 

# Drop the unwanted columns
df_1.drop(['id_symbol','init_date','end_date','multiplier'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Will get back your desired outcome:

```
   id symbol        date  value
0   1      A  2021-02-12    1.0
1   2      B  2021-02-09    1.0
2   1      C  2021-02-14    1.0
3   3      A  2021-02-02    1.0
4   1      A  2021-02-05    5.0
```

A bit of an ad-hoc, but seems to be working.